# Как найти значения, которые отличаются от других в input?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть 4 уникальных поля input, при изменении любого из них, нужно определить, сколько и какие именно значения полей не совпадают. Как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не до конца понимаю суть задачи, но возможно, что такой пример вам поможет:

```js
var inp = $('input').on('input', function() {
    var objVal = inp
        .map((i, el) => {
            return {
                count: 1,
                val: $.trim(el.value)
            };
        }).get()
        .reduce((a, b) => {
            a[b.val] = (a[b.val] || 0) + b.count;
            return a;
        }, {});
    console.log(objVal);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
```